# Can't see a menu for using wireframesketcher in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wireframe

I dont know how to use wireframesketcher in eclipse.
http://wireframesketcher.com/install.html

I've installed it, and now i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your install and eclipse restarts,

> Select Window | Open perspective | Other..., from that menu select "Sketching".

Your view will update with all the Wireframesketcher specific options.

Answer (score 0):

I probably didn't make it obvious enough. In any case it's a good idea to skim through [WireframeSketcher User Guide](http://wireframesketcher.com/help/help.html).